# iTunes encryption Password

Tags: iphone, itunes, backup, encryption

Is there a way to access iTunes encryption password on Windows 10? I can't remember the password and without the password ,I can't restore my backup on a new iPhone. The old iPhone is broken ..

Comment: There are tools to find the password by brute force. I've tried one of them once, but if the password isn't very simple, it can take days or weeks, so I stopped it after a few hours and just setup the iPhone from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

The entire idea of encrypting something is you can't access it without the password. Passwords are never stored anywhere in plain text.

Modern password structures mean that only a hash of the correct input is stored.
If you input the correct password, the hashes match; without the password ever actually been stored anywhere at all, only the 'maths' necessary to test for when it is entered correctly.

So, in short, if you don't have the password, you don't have access to the data.
Not even Apple can unlock it for you.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a stored password on Windows iTunes, unfortunately. Here's a post I maintain with all of my tips for trying to remember the backup password in case it's helpful: https://deciphertools.com/support/knowledge-base/i-forgot-my-iphone-backup-password/